# Finding org-mode bindings

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, help

I sometimes want to insert a new heading without first jumping
to the end of the current tree.  It was fairly simple to guess
that this could be achieved by calling `(org-insert-heading)`,
but from `C-h f` this function didn't seem to be bound to any
key.  I discovered by accident, though, that this function is,
usually, called after `C-c <return>`.  Question: was there any
non-accidental and easy way of discovering this?

Comment: C-h b org-insert-heading   ?

Comment: @Drew, f, sorry

Comment: @gigiair: did you mean `C-h w org-insert-heading RET`? That gives "... not on any key". `C-h b` describes the current set of bindings.

Answer (score 3):

Org mode does a bunch of context-dependent actions by binding a key (e.g. `C-c C-c` or `C-c RET`) to a generic function (`org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` or `org-ctrl-c-ret`). The function looks around to determine a context (am I in a header? or a source block? or a table? etc.) and then calls another function (e.g. `org-insert-heading`) depending on that context.

I don't know of any way to find these context-dependent actions through general emacs mechanisms. You need to consult the doc string of the specific top level function, e.g. `C-h f org-ctrl-c-ret RET`. You might do `C-h f org-ctrl-c- TAB` to find some of these dispatcher-type functions, but there are others as well: e.g `M-RET` is bound to `org-meta-return`.

It might be nice to collect all those in a table somewhere and add them to the Org mode documentation, but AFAIK no such table exists ATM.

Comment: I have often wanted to know what `C-c <return>` or `<tab>` does *in the current context*.   Very frustrating.  Tables in the docs is a good idea.